# How to get Wordpress frontent widget get/post example working on the front end and back end?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, post, get

I was unable to get my wordpress widget to post forms correctly.  I took the advice on this website and researched the issue (see relevant links at the bottom of the post) to see what the problem was.  The first issue was that I could not use "name" for a field.  I needed to make sure that the posted name was unique.  If not, Wordpress would bring me to a "Site Not Found" which was really cryptic.

The key to figuring this out was to start with this example:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

I literally copied and pasted that example into the widget function, of course taking out the html head and tail business.  It did not work because it was posting to "name" which already existed.  Also, the file reference for Wordpress did not start in the plugin directory, but rather the wordpress directory; so it ended up looking in the wrong place for the action.php file that is run after the submit is made.  Look carefully at the URL address bar when the post is made to see if the action is actually getting to the right place.  Finally, I adjusted the address, and everything worked like in the example;  however, it left the main Wordpress page.  So I was stuck.

I put back "" as the action page.  I tried the GET method; that did not work for me (and I am still not sure why, but I should adjust it and check it out because GET is preferable for this application; it allows bookmarks);  it ended up (thank G-d) that the "post" method worked.  (Just now, I changed all occurrences of "post" to "get" and all instances of "POST" to "GET" and it is working as expected.  I was having a problem with GET where the URL was being formed correctly and then I could not access it.  That problem was I was nesting PHP.  I removed all the nested PHP.  Along the route, I updated the initial slider value which was not set correctly.

And finally it works!

Starting Code:

```
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    /* include "thiswidget.php"; */ /*disable for now*/
      /* Include the widget($args, $instance) function body */
      /* include "businesspartnerships.php"; */ /*Original works fine with id update */
    static $recommended_ex_no = 3;
        static $example_run = 4;
       $example_max = 4;
       $example_min = 0;
       $this_widg_id = $this->id;  /* Get the widget ID to be the unique ID Key */

       $default_slider_value = 3;  /*Default slider value if nothing new has been posted */
       if ($example_run > 0) { /*Provide a slider to select examples */
    /*See http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/range_slider.html */
    /*See http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php */
    /*See https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp */

        ?><p> Recommended View Example Number: <?php echo $recommended_ex_no ?></p>
        <!-- See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788005/how-to-get-fetch-html5-range-sliders-value-in-php -->
        <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="range" min="<?php echo $example_min;?>" max="<?php echo $example_max;?>" step="1" value="<?php echo $set_slider_value ?>" id="<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>" name="<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>" onchange='document.getElementById("text_<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>").value = "Slider Value = " + document.getElementById("<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>").value;'/>
    <br><center><input type="text" style="text-align: center" name="text_<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>" id="text_<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>" value="Slider Value = <?php echo $set_slider_value ?>" disabled /></center>
    <br />
    <center><input style="text-align: center" type="submit" value="Submit" /></center>
    </form> 

    <?php
    $this_widg_id = esc_attr( $this->id) ;  /* Get the widget ID to be the unique ID Key */

    echo "The key is : "; echo esc_attr( $this->id); echo "<br><br>";
    if(isset($_POST[esc_attr( $this->id)])){
        echo '<br> isset below get <br>';
        echo "<center>The example selected is: ".$_POST[esc_attr( $this->id)]." </center>";
        // Your Slider value is here, do what you want with it. Mail/Print anything..
            $example_run = $_POST[esc_attr( $this->id)];
            $set_slider_value = $_POST[esc_attr( $this->id)];  /*If the value has been posted, then show it.*/
    } else {
            /* $set_slider_value = $default_slider_value; */ /* Slider value is initially set to default. */ 
    }
    }

    /* Try https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp example here, since form update was not working before */
    ?>
    <!-- <form action="wp-content/plugins/carousel_edit_url_for_newspro/welcome_get.php" method="post"> -->

    <form action="" method="post">

    Name: <input type="text" name="thisexname"><br>
    <!-- E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br> -->
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <?php 
    if (isset($_POST[esc_attr("thisexname")])){
        echo 'Welcome '; echo $_POST["thisexname"]; echo "<br>";
        }
    ?>

    <?php
    /*Setup example runs;  an example run of 0 does not run! */

      if ($example_run > 0) {
        echo '<p>Example content being viewed currently is now example number '.$example_run.':';
        }
```

...

Intermediate code (full Widget Function):

```
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    /* include "thiswidget.php"; */ /*disable for now*/
      /* Include the widget($args, $instance) function body */
      /* include "businesspartnerships.php"; */ /*Original works fine with id update */
    static $recommended_ex_no = 3;
        static $example_run = 4;
       $example_max = 4;
       $example_min = 0;
       $this_widg_id = $this->id;  /* Get the widget ID to be the unique ID Key */

       $default_slider_value = 3;  /*Default slider value if nothing new has been posted */
       if ($example_run > 0) { /*Provide a slider to select examples */
    /*See http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/range_slider.html */
    /*See http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php */
    /*See https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp */

        ?><p> Recommended View Example Number: <?php echo $recommended_ex_no ?></p>
        <!-- See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788005/how-to-get-fetch-html5-range-sliders-value-in-php -->
        <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="range" min="<?php echo $example_min;?>" max="<?php echo $example_max;?>" step="1" value="<?php echo $set_slider_value ?>" id="<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>" name="<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>" onchange='document.getElementById("text_<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>").value = "Slider Value = " + document.getElementById("<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>").value;'/>
    <br><center><input type="text" style="text-align: center" name="text_<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>" id="text_<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>" value="Slider Value = <?php echo $default_slider_value ?>" disabled /></center>
    <br />
    <center><input style="text-align: center" type="submit" value="Submit" /></center>
    </form> 

    <?php
    $this_widg_id = esc_attr( $this->id) ;  /* Get the widget ID to be the unique ID Key */

    echo "The key is : "; echo esc_attr( $this->id); echo "<br><br>";
    if(isset($_GET[esc_attr( $this->id)])){
        echo '<br> isset below get <br>';
        echo "<center>The example selected is: ".$_GET[esc_attr( $this->id)]." </center>";
        // Your Slider value is here, do what you want with it. Mail/Print anything..
            $example_run = $_GET[esc_attr( $this->id)];
            $set_slider_value = $_GET[esc_attr( $this->id)];  /*If the value has been posted, then show it.*/
    } else {
            /* $set_slider_value = $default_slider_value; */ /* Slider value is initially set to default. */ 
    }
    }

    /* Try https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp example here, since form update was not working before */
    ?>
    <!-- <form action="wp-content/plugins/carousel_edit_url_for_newspro/welcome_get.php" method="post"> -->

    <form action="" method="get">

    Name: <input type="text" name="thisexname"><br>
    <!-- E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br> -->
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <?php 
    if (isset($_GET[esc_attr("thisexname")])){
        echo 'Welcome '; echo $_GET["thisexname"]; echo "<br>";
        }
    ?>

    <?php
    /*Setup example runs;  an example run of 0 does not run! */

      if ($example_run > 0) {
        echo '<p>Example content being viewed currently is now example number '.$example_run.':';
        }
      if ($example_run == 1) {
        echo '<p>Example Business Partnerships Begins</p>';
        include "businesspartnerships.php";  /*full copy*/
        echo '<p>Example BP Ends</p>';
        }
      elseif ($example_run == 2) {
        echo '<p>Example for Business Begins</b>';
        include "businesscarousel/business_head.php";  /*content before the loop*/
        include "businesscarousel/business_loop.php";  /*the loop*/
        include "businesscarousel/business_tail.php";  /*content after the loop*/
        echo '<p>Example for Business Ends</b>';
        }
      elseif ($example_run == 3) {
        echo '<p>Example for Books Begins</b>';
        include "bookscarousel/books.php";
        echo '<p>Example for Books Ends</b>';
        }
      elseif ($example_run == 4) {
        echo '<p>Example for Looped Books Begins</b>';
        include "bookscarousel/books_head_vars.php";
        include "bookscarousel/books_head.php";
        include "bookscarousel/books_loop_vars.php";
        include "bookscarousel/books_loop.php";
        include "bookscarousel/books_tail_vars.php";
        include "bookscarousel/books_tail.php";
        echo '<p>Example for Looped Books Ends</b>';
        }
}
```

I finally cleaned up the code a little bit, taking out the examples and just running with the essentials (verified that this basically worked):

```
/**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    /* include "thiswidget.php"; */ /*disable for now*/
      /* Include the widget($args, $instance) function body */
      /* include "businesspartnerships.php"; */ /*Original works fine with id update */
       $example_run = 4;  /*Set to 0 to disable all widget output */
       $example_max = 4;
       $example_min = 0;
       $recommended_ex_no = 4;
       $default_slider_value = 4;  /*Default slider value if nothing new has been posted */

       $this_widg_id = $this->id;  /* Get the widget ID to be the unique ID Key */

       if ($example_run > 0) { /*Provide a slider to select examples */ 
        ?><p> The Recommended Example Number To View is Example Number <?php echo $recommended_ex_no ?>.</p>
        <!-- See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788005/how-to-get-fetch-html5-range-sliders-value-in-php -->
        <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="range" min="<?php echo $example_min;?>" max="<?php echo $example_max;?>" step="1" value="<?php echo $set_slider_value ?>" id="<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>" name="<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>" onchange='document.getElementById("text_<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>").value = "Slider Value = " + document.getElementById("<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>").value;'/>
    <br><center><input type="text" style="text-align: center" name="text_<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>" id="text_<?php echo $this_widg_id; ?>" value="Slider Value = <?php echo $default_slider_value ?>" disabled /></center>
    <br />
    <center><input style="text-align: center" type="submit" value="Submit Slider Value" /></center>
    </form> 

    <?php
    $this_widg_id = esc_attr( $this->id) ;  /* Get the widget ID to be the unique ID Key */

    echo '<br><br><center><p style="text-align: center">This example widget instance is entitled, "'; 
    echo esc_attr( $this->id); echo '".</p></center>';
    if(isset($_GET[esc_attr( $this->id)])){
        /* echo "<center>The example selected is: ".$_GET[esc_attr( $this->id)]." </center>"; */ /*Activate to debug */
        // Your Slider value is here, do what you want with it. Mail/Print anything..
            $example_run = $_GET[esc_attr( $this->id)];
            $set_slider_value = $_GET[esc_attr( $this->id)];  /*If the value has been posted, then show it.*/
        } else {
            $set_slider_value = $default_slider_value; /* Slider value is initially set to default. */ 
        }
    } /*End if example is >0 */
    /* If not working, adapt https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp example here, since form update was not working before */
    /*Setup example runs;  an example run of 0 does not run! */

      if ($example_run > 0) {
        echo '<center><p style="text-align: center">The example content being viewed currently is now example number '.$example_run.':</p>';
        }
      if ($example_run == 1) {
        echo '<p>Example Business Partnerships Begins</p>';
        include "businesspartnerships.php";  /*full copy*/
        echo '<p>Example BP Ends</p>';
        }
      elseif ($example_run == 2) {
        echo '<p>Example for Business Begins</b>';
        include "businesscarousel/business_head.php";  /*content before the loop*/
        include "businesscarousel/business_loop.php";  /*the loop*/
        include "businesscarousel/business_tail.php";  /*content after the loop*/
        echo '<p>Example for Business Ends</b>';
        }
      elseif ($example_run == 3) {
        echo '<p>Example for Books Begins</b>';
        include "bookscarousel/books.php";
        echo '<p>Example for Books Ends</b>';
        }
      elseif ($example_run == 4) {
        echo '<p>Example for Looped Books Begins</b>';
        include "bookscarousel/books_head_vars.php";
        include "bookscarousel/books_head.php";
        include "bookscarousel/books_loop_vars.php";
        include "bookscarousel/books_loop.php";
        include "bookscarousel/books_tail_vars.php";
        include "bookscarousel/books_tail.php";
        echo '<p>Example for Looped Books Ends</b>';
        }
}
```

Also I had to make sure that the double quote " was not being used where the better ' quote unquote ' should be used.

Any advice to do this better?

And the next part of the question:  how is this done on the back-end in the widgets appearance part of the admin screen?

The code I have for the back-end functions is (two-parts):

```
    public function form( $instance ) {
        /*  
        $title - site title
        $url_config - private key to website or local file for include
      $category_name_textbox - name of the category used for the widget in the textbox
            $category_name - name of the category used for the widget  
      $posts_to_show - number of posts to show
        */

        $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : esc_html__( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
        $url_config = ! empty( $instance['url_config'] ) ? $instance['url_config'] : esc_html__( 'Display All', 'text_domain' );        
    $category_name_textbox = ! empty( $instance['category_name_textbox'] ) ? $instance['category_name_textbox'] : esc_html__( 'uncategorized', 'text_domain' );
    $category_name = ! empty( $instance['$category_name'] ) ? $instance['$category_name'] : esc_html__( 'uncategorized', 'text_domain' );
        $posts_to_show = ! empty( $instance['$posts_to_show'] ) ? $instance['posts_to_show'] : esc_html__( '4', 'text_domain' );
        include "form_html.php";
    }
```

The include "form_html.php" is included near the end of "public function form( $instance ) " to make the code more readable and also to highlight the issue.  Its contents are here:

```
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Title:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">

        </p><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id('url_config' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'URL Config:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'url_config' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'url_config' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $url_config ); ?>">
        </p>

        </p><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id('category_name_textbox' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Category Name:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'category_name_textbox' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'category_name_textbox' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $category_name_textbox ); ?>">
        </p>

        <p>
            <label><?php _e( 'Category', 'newsmag-pro' ); ?> :</label>
            <select name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'newsmag_category' ) ); ?>"
                    id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'newsmag_category' ) ); ?>">
                <option value="" <?php if ( empty( $instance['newsmag_category'] ) ) {
                    echo 'selected="selected"';
                } ?>><?php _e( '&ndash; Select a category &ndash;', 'newsmag-pro' ) ?></option>
                <?php
                $categories = get_categories( 'hide_empty=0' );
                foreach ( $categories as $category ) { ?>
                    <option
                        value="<?php echo esc_attr( $category->slug ); ?>" <?php selected( esc_attr( $category->slug ), $instance['newsmag_category'] ); ?>><?php echo esc_attr( $category->cat_name ); ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </p>
<p>Selected Category: <? echo $instance['newsmag_category'] ?></p>


        <label class="block" for="input_<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'show_post' ) ); ?>">
            <span class="customize-control-title">
               <?php _e( 'Posts to Show', 'newsmag-pro' ); ?> :
            </span>
        </label>

        <input type="text" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'show_post' ) ); ?>" class="rl-slider"
               id="input_<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'show_post' ) ); ?>"
               value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['show_post'] ); ?>" />

        <div id="slider_<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'show_post' ) ) ?>" data-attr-min="4"
             data-attr-max="12" data-attr-step="1" class="ss-slider"></div>


        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                $('[id="slider_<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'show_post' ) ); ?>"]').slider({
                    value: <?php echo esc_attr( $instance['show_post'] ); ?>,
                    range: 'min',
                    min  : 4,
                    max  : 12,
                    step : 1,
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        $('[id="input_<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'show_post' ) ); ?>"]').val(ui.value).keyup();
                    }
                });
                $('[id="input_<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'show_post' ) ) ?>"]').on('focus', function(){
                    $('[id="input_<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'show_post' ) ) ?>"]').trigger('blur');
                });
                $('[id="input_<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'show_post' ) ) ?>"]').val($('[id="slider_<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'show_post' ) ) ?>"]').slider("value"));
                $('[id="input_<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'show_post' ) ) ?>"]').change(function () {
                    $('[id="slider_<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'show_post' ) ) ?>"]').slider({
                        value: $(this).val()
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
<?php
```

So what is going wrong on the back-end?  I can select the drop-down and it does not update anything.  And I can adjust the slider bar, but then I cannot reference its value later to save its value.  Any ideas how to solve the back-end website management aspect of this problem?

Because I am just registering, the references are limited to two.  So you can find the more complete reference list at:

http://newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/technology/stephen-elliott/technical-programming-questions/

By the way, if you go to the main website:

```
http://www.newyorkbusinessreview.com/
```

The main site currently redirects while still under construction to:

```
http://www.newyorkbusinessreview.com/wordpress/
```

I may have the plugin front-end disabled to not bring down the site while I am still working on the issues.

Comment: Wow... this is a huge wall of code... any change of trimming this down to the core of the problem? . See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I basically copied and pasted the part of the code that had to do with the slider and the text box, just modifying the names and ID's slightly.  On the back end it is easy to output values in a text box.  That seems to have solved it.  The slider now works on the back end and it updates the text box also inside the widget form there!

If any additional detail is wanted, please let me know so I can provide code samples if desired.