# Updated:How to display data form database in range slider?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get the data from the database and one data need display into range slider. I using PHP foreach to display data. However, how can display one of the data in range slider form? I have not an idea to display the range slider value on the table. Does anyone know how doing?

**Updated code**

```
<?php 
try{
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gcmes", "root", "");
$sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM details");


echo"<table class='info' align='center'>";
echo"<tr><td width='10'><b>No</b></td>
<td width='30'><b>Category</b></td>
<td width='50'><b>Job</b></td>
<td width='40'><b>Evaluate</b></td>
<td width='30'><b>Marks</b></td><tr>";
foreach($sql as $row) {
$Item = $row["Item"];
$Category = $row["Category"];
$Job = $row["Job"];
$Evaluate = $row["Hole 6"];
echo'
    <tr>
        <td>' . $Item . '</td>
        <td>' . $Category . '</td>
        <td>' . $Job . '</td>
        <td><div id="slidecontainer"><input type="range" min="1" max="5" value="' . $Evaluate . '" class="slider" id="myRange">
        </td>
        <td><span id="demo"></span>
        <script>
        var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
        var output = document.getElementById("demo");
        output.innerHTML = slider.value;
        slider.oninput = function() {
          output.innerHTML = this.value;
          }
          </script>
          </td>
    </tr>
';

}
echo"</table>"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e) { echo "error".$e->getMessage(); }
?>
```

**Now I facing the table only display only one of the value of slider other not display the value but the slider have value. Image will show the result**

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrIFl.png)

It's the code wrong? Anyone know? Thanks

Comment: does $Evaluate = $row["Hole 6"] returns the value that is stored in db?

Comment: I want the value in 2 form, one is the int and else is a slider. If the user changes the range and clicks the update button will store in db.

Comment: Try to implement the slider as shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp).. in the value attribute write _value='$Evaluate'_ to display the correct value of each element. If you want then to update the value try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788005/how-to-get-fetch-html5-range-sliders-value-in-php). Tell me if it helps so i can post it as an answer.

Comment: Implement the slider is okay already, but I cannot display the update value the slider value  when the slider change in `$Evaluate = $row["Hole 6"];`

Comment: i think the link i gave you above is more than clear... try that and update the question with your new code.

Comment: I have updated the code, can help me see the problem. Thank you

Comment: You are trying a JS script inside PHP... basically you are mixing server side with client side, which is not possible, unless you put ajax as a middle man. Do you want to update your value on a click of a button?

Comment: Yes, I want to update the value after click a button.

Answer (score 0):

If `$Hole6` is a numeric value, you can use a default [range slider](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp)

Change the following line:

```
echo"<tr><td>$Item</td><td>$Category</td><td>$Job</td><td>$Evaluate</td><td>$Hole6</td></tr>";
```

to

```
echo'
        <tr>
            <td>' . $Item . '</td>
            <td>' . $Category . '</td>
            <td>' . $Job . '</td>
            <td>' . $Evaluate . '</td>
            <td><input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="' . $Hole6 . '"></td>
        </tr>
    ';
```

And for the second part; you can do that with jQuery really easy. I made you an example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" id="slider1"></td>
        <td><span id="value1">50</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="70" id="slider2"></td>
        <td><span id="value2">70</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type=range]').on("input", function () {
            var sid = this.id.substr(6);
            var val = $(this).val();
            $("#value" + sid).text(val);
        });
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you and I get it already. Now I facing how to display the value when slider change it? In The next column

Comment: and how do you plan to update the value in the database with that?

Comment: The code cannot apply to my code because I just set one time and display row by row. Cannot set 2-time id of the slider.

Comment: Whit your code, all your sliders have the same ID. And that&#39;s wrong. See https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute so you need to update it with unique id's. After that you can apply my code.

Comment: See my example. Do you have row id's? In your database? You can use these. Otherwise you can use a counter

Comment: I don't have row id's, but I have Item is primary key it's same? 
If I use counter, how to write the code or can you provide same link/reference to mee?

Comment: What is the name of the element in the database? The primarykey?

Comment: The primary key is Item(Varcha). The element is hole(inside is int) which is the mark of evaluate

Answer (score 0):

First of wrap your `<table>` with `<form action="yourfile.php" method="post">`

Then put a `name` attribute to your slider.

`<td><div id="slidecontainer"><input type="range" min="1" max="5" value="$Evaluate" name="slider" class="slider" id="myRange">`

You will need an `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>` before the `</form>` is closed.

Inside `<?php?>` you need to check:

`if (isset($_POST['submit'])) //if submit is pressed
{
$newValueOfSlider = $_POST['slider']; //this takes the value of the slider
}`

Then add your variable to a `SQL` query to update the database.